# Average of cell content based on day of month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm attempting to get an average number of calls/day based on yesterday's date.

My initial formula looks like this: `=round(average(C24/3),2)`, where:
C24 = the total number of calls,
/3  = diving the contents of C24 by yesterday (assuming yesterday was the 3rd of the month),
,2 = rounding answer to 2 decimal places.

The formula itself works fine, but I have to go in daily to change the 'date' (/3, in my example).

Any suggestions as to how I can automate this formula so as to not have to go in to change the day of the month every day?

(for what it's worth, i tried using `=round(average(C24/today()),2)`, but get a divide by zero error. Not sure what else to try. I also googled rolling averages/moving averages, but that didn't seem to help either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DAY` and `TODAY`.

```
=DAY(TODAY()-1)
```

So

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(C24/DAY(TODAY()-1)),2)
```